# Emacs helm: How to auto-recenter after jump?

Tags: emacs, emacs-helm

I would like to recenter current line after jumping by using helm-semantic-or-imenu or helm-org-in-buffer-headings, i.e., just like helm-swoop.  Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't use `helm`, but I do this for `isearch`.  Figure out which function actually jumps to a line (maybe the called function, e.g. `helm-semantic-or-imenu`, maybe some internal helper function as is the case for `isearch`), then add the following advice to it.

```
(defun recenter-no-redraw (&optional arg)
  "Like `recenter', but no redrawing."
  (interactive "P")
  (let ((recenter-redisplay nil))
    (recenter arg)))

(advice-add 'isearch-search
            :after
            (lambda (&rest args)
              "Recenter"
              (when isearch-success
                (recenter-no-redraw))))
```

I can't remember why I defined a non-redrawing version of `recenter` (I've had it like that for years).  It should work with plain `recenter` also.

Comment: It works!  I used:
`(advice-add 'helm-semantic-or-imenu :after (lambda (&rest args) (recenter-no-redraw)))`

Thanks!